# The converse for the basis of tensor product of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

I have been studying the tensor product of Hilbert spaces, and I know that if ${\psi_k}$ and ${\phi_l}$ are orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ respectively, then ${\psi_k\otimes\phi_l}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$. My question is, is the converse statement true?. Is it true the following statement:

Let $\{\lambda_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$. Then, there exist orthonormal basis ${\psi_k}$ and ${\phi_l}$ of $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ respectively, such that $\lambda_n=\psi_k\otimes\phi_l$ for every $\lambda_n$?

Comment: Consider a simple finite-dimensional example. Fix a non-pure tensor $\Lambda_1$ (these exist, barring a few exceptional choices of $\mathcal{H}_{1,2}$). Then, we can normalize it to get $\lambda_1$; this is still non-pure. We can extend this to an orthonormal basis of the tensor product. But again, $\lambda_1$ is not a pure-tensor so no such $\psi$’s and $\phi$’s can exist.